# Multiple ViewModels for Add and Edit (WPF, MVVM)

Tags: mvvm, view, viewmodel

I have done some research online and I have come up with some conflicting answers. Here is my situation:

I have a EditClient view which references the ClientViewModel and I have an AddClient view which also references the ClientViewModel. Naturally, edit and add operations are different and the logic in the ViewModel differs somewhat.

Would it be appropriate to have an EditViewModel and an AddViewModel and have them referenced by their respective views? Is this considered valid MVVM structure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, i would have one ViewModel per View. But the ViewModel would of course work with the same Model.